# Joining a second instance of Sales table to get last weeks Sales

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a Sales table showing product number, sales value, and sales volume per week. I need to build a report to display these values and volumes along with the equivalent values from the previous week. I also have a Weeks table which gives me the previous week number for the current week (for instance if current week is 2013-01, then the previous week value is 2012-52).

I therefore assumed it would be simple enough to join to another instance of Sales on product number and previous week number from the Weeks table. However Teradata is not letting me do this, initially it threw an error of `Improper column reference in the search condition of a joined table` and when I re-ordered the query to reference Weeks before the second instance of Sales it now tries to run but gives me a `No more spool space` error, so I assume my approach is incorrect. My SQL is as follows:

```
select s.Week_Number,
       s.Product_Number,
       s.Sales_Value,
       s.Sales_Volume,
       s_lw.Sales_Value,
       s_lw.Sales_Volume

   from SALES s
  inner join WEEKS w 
     on s.Week_Number = w.Week_Number
   left join SALES s_lw 
     on     s.Product_Number = s_lw.Product_Number
        and s_lw.Week_Number = w.Last_week_Number
```

Could anyone please suggest what I'm doing wrong here? It seems like this should be achievable.

Comment: I think the last line should be `and s_lw.Week_Number = w.Last_week_Number`. As you have it now s.Week_Number has to equal both week numbers at the same time. I don't think that explains your error messages though.

Comment: Yes, you're quite right. Didn't copy it over correctly, thanks for pointing out

Comment: Is your above query being used to create a table for your report? If so it's important to remember that the first col in your "SELECT" list is by default the `primary index`.  If the values in this column are mostly not unique then you could run into spool space errors like you experienced.

Comment: No, I'm only using this to return data. I've tried setting up an equivalent query using temp tables and that runs fine, so there this be something to do with Sales table. The Sales table is actually a View but I shouldn't think that would stop this working. Maybe I'm just going to have to fnid another way, which is annoying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a Window Aggregate Function to accomplish this with a single pass of the `SALES` table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       s.Week_Number,
       s.Product_Number,
       s.Sales_Value,
       s.Sales_Volume,
       MAX(s.Sales_Value) OVER (PARTITION BY s.Product_Number 
                                    ORDER BY s.Week_Number DESC 
                                ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS LW_Sales_Value,
       MAX(s.Sales_Volume) OVER (PARTITION BY s.Product_Number
                                    ORDER BY s.Week_Number DESC 
                                ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS LW_Sales_Volume
  FROM SALES s;
```

Comment: Many thanks, that's a good way of getting round the issue, and as you suggest is no doubt more efficient